# Getting file in hex format - my output vs xxd command output

Tags: c, filesize, fgets, hexdump, xxd

I'm trying to write a simple program to generate hex output from file. This is my `two.c` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int 
main(void) {
    printf("%s\n", "Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

which was compiled in this way:

```
 gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors two.c -o two
```

so I have `two` executable file.

Now, I wrote a program to read that file and show the binary (hexadecimal) output of it. This is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int 
fileSize(FILE *ptr) {

    int size = 0;
    fseek(ptr, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(ptr);
    fseek(ptr, 0, SEEK_SET);
    return size;

}

int 
main(void) {

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("two", "rb");
    int sz = fileSize(fp);
    char buff[ sz ];

    if (!fp) 
        printf("%s\n", "Not great at all");

    else 
        while (!feof(fp)) {
            fgets(buff, sz, fp);
            for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
                printf("%02x%02x ", (buff[i] & 0xFF), (buff[i+1] & 0xFF));
                if (!(i % 8))
                    printf("\n");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

    fclose(fp);

}
```

And here is huge output of it http://pastebin.com/RVLy6H9B

The problem is, when I use linux command `xxd two > two.hex` I'm getting completely different output (it's not about formatting) and there is only about 500 lines of bytes, not about 8k like in my output.

xxd output: http://pastebin.com/Gw9wg93g

Where is the problem? Is something wrong with reading function `fgets(buff, sz, fp);`?

Comment: here `fp = fopen("two", "rb");` which file you are opening `two.c `or `two.o` ?

Comment: I'm opening `two` file - the output of gcc compilation.

Comment: ....and [`while (!feof(fp))` **is wrong**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgets()` stops reading after an EOF or **a newline**. But your code always loops `sz` times.

`fgets()` is not the right function to read binary data. You could use `fread()` instead.

Comment: @python: also, you don't need to read the whole file at once. You could read it `BUFSIZ` bytes at a time.

Comment: Yes, I know. I just wanted to see how reading works at all :)